# Formatting a Double to show only the first 2 decimals

Tags: java, double, number-formatting

I have a management software for invoices that creates a pdf document with the values inputed by the user in the various fields (product's price, quantity, reference etc.).

I need to modify the code that controls the displaying of the product's price to obtain the price always formatted to show only the first two decimals.

Example: when the user inputs the value `12,36789 €`, in the pdf this value is displayed exactly as it is (`12,36789 €`); I would like to display `12,36 €`.

The code is the following:
`$V{Formatter}.format(new Double($F{importoUnitario}.replaceAll(",",".")))+" "+$P{valutaSimbolo}`

the first part
`$V{Formatter}.format(new Double($F{importoUnitario}.replaceAll(",",".")))`
controls the value itself (12,36)

the middle part
`+" "`
it's just a blank space between the value and the symbol

the last part
`+$P{valutaSimbolo}`
is the currency symbol

How do I do this?

Comment: Well, I could give you an answer for Java, but that code you've shown us doesn't look like Java to me.  Perhaps you should tag this question with a different language, to get the right help.

Comment: I'm not so experienced in programming, so maybe this is not a "fully-Java" code...maybe it's just based on Java, I don't know sorry. The thing I can tell you is that I retrieved that code from the pdf template editor that I have inside my management software: through this editor, I can also view the source code, so I've been able to see the code that I have posted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Gianluca it looks like your PDF template editor has its own language.  It's a bit Java-like, but it has some syntax that isn't Java.  I'm not familiar with your PDF template editor, so I don't know what this language can and can't do.  You might have to work this out from the documentation for the template editor.

Comment: Ok, thank you @DawoodibnKareem for the help...anyway, yes, I think that the editor is made with a sort of "custom language" based on Java. I will try to figure out how to manage this.